how do I copy uint16 bytes from one array into a MATLABString in mex C++
I have a matrix of bytes, or for this example we can assume I've converted to uint16. I am curious how to copy a subset of the data elements into a MATLABString (i.e., using the mex C++ interface). I asked ChatGPT but it is using a charArray and not a string. It also looks like it has an unnecessary data copy going on at the end (I could be wrong about that). It also is not clear why I need an iterator but that may be because I am used to C and working more with pointers. Is this the best approach? The original solution had a loop to copy/cast each element but I asked it to use memcpy as I'm under the impression that memcpy may be faster and also just seems like it should be the right way to copy a lot of data from one array to another.
#include "mex.hpp"
#include "mexAdapter.hpp"

class MexFunction : public matlab::mex::Function {
public:
    void operator()(matlab::mex::ArgumentList outputs, matlab::mex::ArgumentList inputs) override {
        // Check input and output arguments
        checkArguments(outputs, inputs);

        // Get input arguments
        matlab::data::TypedArray<uint16_t> data = std::move(inputs[0]);
        double startIndex = inputs[1][0];
        double endIndex = inputs[2][0];
        size_t subsetLength = static_cast<size_t>(endIndex - startIndex + 1);

        // Check bounds
        size_t dataSize = data.getNumberOfElements();
        if (startIndex < 1 || endIndex >= dataSize || startIndex > endIndex) {
            matlab::engine::MATLABException::throwAsCaller("Subset indices are out of bounds.");
        }

        // Extract subset of uint16 array
        matlab::data::TypedArray<uint16_t>::iterator subsetData = data.begin() + static_cast<size_t>(startIndex) - 1;

        // Convert subset to character array using memcpy
        std::string charArray(subsetLength, '\0');
        memcpy(&charArray[0], subsetData, subsetLength * sizeof(uint16_t));

        // Create MATLABString
        outputs[0] = factory.createCharArray(charArray);
    }

private:
    matlab::data::ArrayFactory factory;

    void checkArguments(matlab::mex::ArgumentList outputs, matlab::mex::ArgumentList inputs) {
        if (inputs.size() != 3) {
            matlab::engine::MATLABException::throwAsCaller("Three input arguments required.");
        }
        if (outputs.size() != 1) {
            matlab::engine::MATLABException::throwAsCaller("One output argument required.");
        }
        if (!inputs[0].isUint16() || !inputs[1].isDouble() || !inputs[2].isDouble()) {
            matlab::engine::MATLABException::throwAsCaller("Inputs must be uint16 and double arrays.");
        }
    }
};



The "string" type in MATLAB is an opaque type, meaning the data areas are not held as simple arrays of elements behind pointers like the usual numeric or char variables are, but are hidden to the user in an undocumented way. I doubt you will be able to convert your uint16 data into a string without a deep copy. And I doubt you will be able to use memcpy() for this either since I don't think you have access to the underlying data pointer in a MATLAB string.

Thanks James! To be clear I am expecting that I will need memory allocation, I am just trying to avoid creating a loop that does a byte by byte assignment (as opposed to using memcpy). The C++ mex interface describes interfacing with the string arrays (unlike the C interface) and the C++ interface does have from/to buffer support which does expose the pointers. I acknowledge I may not be able to guarantee no unnecessary allocations with the std::move or related calls but I was hoping to find "the right way" of moving subsets of bytes into strings.

My C++ foo is poor though so the easy way may be the only way.

What exactly is in your array of bytes? According to the doc, MATLAB stores strings (and char) arrays in the background as UTF-16, so unless your bytes have this encoding I fail to see how a memcpy() like function can work. I don't use the C++ interface myself so am unsure how they expose the data pointers as you mention, and what functions MATLAB provides for using these pointers.

I'm parsing a binary file and at the "intermediate" stage of parsing I have a matrix of UTF-16 data that is null-padded (per column). Eventually I might get a bit earlier in the pipeline and have raw bytes that need to be encoded, but the native2unicode function doesn't work well because of the multi-entry (matrix) nature. Looping through native2unicode proved to be extremely slow. At this point I'm trying to understand how to work with strings in C++ mex as I have no prior experience with the C++ approach and I find the documentation to be confusing (and C mex is not good for strings).

relevant, I think: https://www.mathworks.com/support/search.html/answers/436916-how-to-access-raw-data-via-the-mex-c-api.html

Here's the answer I came up with. Note, it is not performant (details below). I am also not an expert at the C++ MATLAB interface so this is largely for reference in hopes that it helps others with related issues.
Code:
#include "mex.hpp"
#include "mexAdapter.hpp"
#include <cstring>

namespace md = matlab::data;
namespace mx = matlab::mex;

class MexFunction : public mx::Function {
    md::ArrayFactory factory;
    std::shared_ptr<matlab::engine::MATLABEngine> matlabPtr = getEngine();

public:
    void operator()(mx::ArgumentList outputs, mx::ArgumentList inputs) {

        checkArguments(outputs, inputs);

        //Prep of the input
        //--------------------------------
        md::TypedArray<uint16_t> input_matrix = std::move(inputs[0]);
        size_t n_rows = input_matrix.getDimensions()[0];
        size_t n_cols = input_matrix.getDimensions()[1];
        md::buffer_ptr_t<uint16_t> input_buffer = input_matrix.release();
        uint16_t *input_pointer = (uint16_t *)input_buffer.get();
        uint16_t *input_pointer2 = input_pointer;

        //Prep of the output
        //---------------------------------------------------
        md::StringArray myArray = factory.createArray<md::MATLABString>({n_cols,1});

        for (size_t i = 0; i < n_cols; ++i){
            md::buffer_ptr_t<char16_t> temp_buffer = factory.createBuffer<char16_t>(n_rows);
            std::memcpy(temp_buffer.get(), input_pointer2, n_rows*2);
            
            myArray[i] = temp_buffer.get();

            input_pointer2 += n_rows;
        }

        outputs[0] = myArray;

    }
private:
    void checkArguments(mx::ArgumentList outputs, mx::ArgumentList inputs) {

        //https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/handling-inputs-and-outputs.html

        if (inputs.size() != 1) {
            mexErrMsgIdAndTxt(u"copy_test:invalid_input:one_input_check",u"there must be 1 input to copy_test4");
        }
        if (inputs[0].getType() != md::ArrayType::UINT16) {
            mexErrMsgIdAndTxt(u"copy_test:invalid_input:uint16_check", u"Input must be a matrix of type uint16");
        }
        if (inputs[0].getDimensions().size() != 2) {
            mexErrMsgIdAndTxt(u"copy_test:invalid_input:2d_check", u"Input must be a 2D matrix.");
        }
        if (outputs.size() != 1) {
            mexErrMsgIdAndTxt(u"copy_test:invalid_input:one_output_check",u"there must be 1 output to copy_test4");
        }
    }

    void mexErrMsgIdAndTxt(md::String id, md::String error_string){
        matlabPtr->feval(u"error", 0, std::vector<md::Array>({factory.createScalar(id),factory.createScalar(error_string)}));
    }
};

Here is some test code:
temp = reshape(uint16(41:1040),10,100);
temp = repmat(temp,1,10000);
N = 10;
tic
for i = 1:N
temp2 = copy_test5(temp);
end
toc/N

tic
for i = 1:N
temp3 = string(char(temp'));
end
toc/N


I don't have exact times handy but we're looking at the code being twice as slow as simply calling char then string. My guess is that the methods provided have enough overhead that the mex code is not worth it.
I was going to put string stripping in the code as well, but decided against it since simply doing the translation from the matrix to individual strings was so slow in mex.
I'll note in this process that I forgot a lot of the delay in running this code involves the numerous string allocations, as opposed to other factors.
